# como mantener la sesión abierta cuando inicio sesión en mi pagina web con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy aprendiendo a usar html, css y javascript, y estoy practicando creando una pagina web tipo foro (algo parecida es esta misma web), ya tengo las distintas paginas que componen mi proyecto ya creados con html y css, y ahora estoy trabajando en el dinamismos y las funcionalidades con el javascript. pero no se como hacer que mi pagina wed habilite algunas funciones cuando inicio sesión y que se mantenga abierta cuando voy de una pagina a otra (por ejemplo si voy del home al perfil) y que se mantenga abierto mi cuenta. si pueden ayudarme se los agradeceré.

PD: tengo pensado usar usar base de dato (sqlite) mas adelante, pero no me gustaria usarlo si no es estrictamente necesario

Comment: Si no estas usando base de datos y solo estas usando HTML ¿Como inicias sesión?

Comment: Puedes usar cookies o localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Yo en estos casos uso `localStorage`. `localStorage` es el almacenamiento local de un ordenador, y un lugar donde puedes almacenar información. `localStorage` solo acepta cadenas de texto, asi que, un ejemplo podria ser:

```css
var save = document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
localStorage.setItem("valor", "hola");
});
var print = document.getElementById('btn3').addEventListener('click', function () {

document.write(localStorage.getItem("valor"));
});
var rm = document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', function () {
lcoalStorage.removeItem("valor");
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id="btn">Guardar una cosa en localstorage</button>
<br><br>
<button id="btn3">Imprimir por pantalla lo que hay en localstorage</button>
<br><br>
<button id="btn2">Eliminar esa cosa de localstorage</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Tienes que copiar y pegar ese código en tu editor de código para que te funcione bien.

> ## Explicación de métodos *localStorage*:
>
> > ### setItem("llave", "valor")
> >
> > Guarda un elemento en *localStorage*. La `llave` es su especie de "id" (se utiliza en los otros métodos) y el `valor`, tal como indica su nombre, es el valor de la `llave` que le has asignado al elemento
>
> > ### getItem("llave")
> >
> > Obtiene el elemento con el supesto "id" de `llave` que previamente guardaste en localStorage por medio de la `llave`.
>
> > ### removeItem('llave')
> >
> > tal como el nombre del método indica, elimina el elemento con la "id" `llave` (el elemento está compuesto por `llave` y `valor`, y este método elimina a los dos)

## ¡Ojo!

### Recuerda que *`localStorage`* solo admite **cadenas de texto (string)**, y  por lo tanto devuelve cadenas de texto también.